# Flutter - How do I call a Parent widget function from child widget while also maintaining the state with a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing, flutter-provider

I have the following code structure: Parent --> Child --> GrandChild. I need to call the function in parent from grandchild. Also, a boolean variable needs to be available in both parent and grandchild for UI changes (keeping them in sync). How do I do this?

HomeScreen: (Parent Widget)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:voice_recorder/recording_info_provider.dart';

import 'central_icons_widget.dart';
import 'digital_display.dart';
import 'record_button_with_outer_circle_and_shadow.dart';
import 'recording_state.dart';
import 'recordings_list.dart';



///
const int tSampleRate = 44000;
typedef _Fn = void Function();

/// Example app.
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  FlutterSoundPlayer? _mPlayer = FlutterSoundPlayer();
  FlutterSoundRecorder? _mRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  bool _mPlayerIsInited = false;
  bool _mRecorderIsInited = false;
  bool _mplaybackReady = false;
  String? _mPath;
  StreamSubscription? _mRecordingDataSubscription;

  Future<void> _openRecorder() async {
    var statusMicPermission = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (statusMicPermission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      throw RecordingPermissionException('Microphone permission not granted');
    }

    var statusStoragePermission =
        await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    if (statusStoragePermission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      throw Exception('Storage permission not granted');
    }
    await _mRecorder!.openAudioSession();
    setState(() {
      _mRecorderIsInited = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Be careful : openAudioSession return a Future.
    // Do not access your FlutterSoundPlayer or FlutterSoundRecorder before the completion of the Future
    _mPlayer!.openAudioSession().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _mPlayerIsInited = true;
      });
    });
    _openRecorder();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stopPlayer();
    _mPlayer!.closeAudioSession();
    _mPlayer = null;

    stopRecorder();
    _mRecorder!.closeAudioSession();
    _mRecorder = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<Directory> _createFolder() async {
    final folderName = "voice_recorder";
    final dir = Directory("storage/emulated/0/$folderName");
    if (await dir.exists()) {
      // TODO:
      print("exist");
    } else {
      // TODO:
      print("not exist");
      dir.create();
    }
    return dir;
  }

  Future<IOSink> createFile() async {
    // var tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // _mPath = '${tempDir!.path}/flutter_sound_example.pcm';

    var directory = await _createFolder();
    _mPath = '${directory.path}/flutter_sound_example.pcm';

    var outputFile = File(_mPath!);
    if (outputFile.existsSync()) {
      await outputFile.delete();
    }
    return outputFile.openWrite();
  }


  Future<void> record() async {
    assert(_mRecorderIsInited && _mPlayer!.isStopped);
    var sink = await createFile();
    var recordingDataController = StreamController<Food>();
    _mRecordingDataSubscription =
        recordingDataController.stream.listen((buffer) {
      if (buffer is FoodData) {
        sink.add(buffer.data!);
      }
    });
    await _mRecorder!.startRecorder(
      toStream: recordingDataController.sink,
      codec: Codec.pcm16,
      numChannels: 1,
      sampleRate: tSampleRate,
    );
    //isRecording = _mRecorder!.isRecording;

    setState(() {});
  }


  Future<void> stopRecorder() async {
    await _mRecorder!.stopRecorder();
    if (_mRecordingDataSubscription != null) {
      await _mRecordingDataSubscription!.cancel();
      _mRecordingDataSubscription = null;
    }
    _mplaybackReady = true;
  }

  _Fn? getRecorderFn() {
    // RecordingState.isRecording = !RecordingState.isRecording;
    // setState(() {});
    // RecordingInfoProvider recordingInfoProvider =
    //     Provider.of<RecordingInfoProvider>(context, listen: false);

    // recordingInfoProvider.updateRecordingStatus();

    if (!_mRecorderIsInited || !_mPlayer!.isStopped) {
      return null;
    }
    return _mRecorder!.isStopped
        ? () {
            record;
          }
        : () {
            //stopRecorder().then((value) => setState(() {}));
            stopRecorder;
          };
  }

  Function? toggleRecording() {
    if (!_mRecorderIsInited || !_mPlayer!.isStopped) {
      return null;
    }
    return _mRecorder!.isStopped
        ? () {
            record;
          }
        : () {
            //stopRecorder().then((value) => setState(() {}));
            stopRecorder;
          };
  }

  void play() async {
    assert(_mPlayerIsInited &&
        _mplaybackReady &&
        _mRecorder!.isStopped &&
        _mPlayer!.isStopped);
    await _mPlayer!.startPlayer(
        fromURI: _mPath,
        sampleRate: tSampleRate,
        codec: Codec.pcm16,
        numChannels: 1,
        whenFinished: () {
          setState(() {});
        }); // The readability of Dart is very special :-(
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> stopPlayer() async {
    await _mPlayer!.stopPlayer();
  }

  _Fn? getPlaybackFn() {
    if (!_mPlayerIsInited || !_mplaybackReady || !_mRecorder!.isStopped) {
      return null;
    }
    return _mPlayer!.isStopped
        ? play
        : () {
            stopPlayer().then((value) => setState(() {}));
          };
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RecordingInfoProvider recordingInfoProvider =
        Provider.of<RecordingInfoProvider>(context, listen: false);

    bool _isRecording = recordingInfoProvider.getRecordingStatus();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
            //FROSTED GLASS BACKGROUND
            Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(25),
            ),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ),
          //child: Expanded(
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 5,
              sigmaY: 5,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                //TIMER (Digital Display)
                DigitalDisplay(), //isRecording SHOULD UPDATE THIS WIDGET

                //RECORD BUTTON
//isRecording SHOULD UPDATE THIS WIDGET
                RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadow(
                  //outerCircleSize: outerCircleSize,
                  //isRecording: _isRecording, /
                  toggleRecording: () {},
                ),

                //MUSIC AND SETTINGS
                CentralIconsWidget(),

                //RECORDINGS LIST
                RecordingsList(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//typedef VoidCallback = void Function();
```

RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadow:

```
      import 'package:blobs/blobs.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
  import 'package:voice_recorder/recording_state.dart';

  import 'constants.dart';
  import 'home_screen.dart';
  import 'record_button_with_shadow.dart';
  import 'recording_info_provider.dart';

  class RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadow extends StatefulWidget {
    RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadow({
      Key? key,
      required this.toggleRecording,
      //required this.isRecording,
    }) : //_isRecording = isRecording,
          super(key: key);

    final Function? toggleRecording;
    //final VoidCallback? toggleRecording;
    //final bool isRecording;
    @override
    State<RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadow> createState() =>
        _RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadowState();
  }

  class _RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadowState
      extends State<RecordButtonWithOuterCircleAndShadow> {
    bool _isRecording = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      RecordingInfoProvider recordingInfoProvider =
          Provider.of<RecordingInfoProvider>(context, listen: false);
      _isRecording = recordingInfoProvider.getRecordingStatus();

      var outerCircleSize = 275.0;

      return Container(
        child:
            //widget.isRecording
            _isRecording
                ? Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: outerCircleSize,
                        width: outerCircleSize,

                        //SHADOW AND BUTTON
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                          child: RecordButtonWithShadow(
                            toggleRecording: widget.toggleRecording,
                            //isRecording: _isRecording,
                            size: _isRecording ? 80 : 200,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Blob.animatedRandom(
                        size: 325,
                        styles: BlobStyles(
                          color: kRecordButtonColor,
                          fillType: BlobFillType.stroke,
                          //minGrowth:6,
                          //gradient: LinearGradient(),
                          strokeWidth: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : Container(
                    height: outerCircleSize,
                    width: outerCircleSize,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150),
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: _isRecording ? 5 : 3,
                        color: _isRecording ? kRecordButtonColor : Colors.grey,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                      ),
                    ),

                    //SHADOW AND BUTTON
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                      child: RecordButtonWithShadow(
                        toggleRecording: widget.toggleRecording,
                        //isRecording: _isRecording,
                        size: _isRecording ? 80 : 200,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
      );
    }
  }

  //typedef VoidCallback = void Function(context);
```

RecordButtonWithShadow:

```
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'dart:math';

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

  import 'constants.dart';
  import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';

  import 'recording_info_provider.dart';
  import 'recording_state.dart';

  class RecordButtonWithShadow extends StatefulWidget {
    RecordButtonWithShadow({
      Key? key,
      required this.toggleRecording,
      //required this.isRecording,
      required this.size,
    }) : super(key: key);

    //final bool isRecording;
    final double size;
    //final VoidCallback? toggleRecording;
    final Function? toggleRecording;

    @override
    _RecordButtonWithShadowState createState() => _RecordButtonWithShadowState();
  }

  class _RecordButtonWithShadowState extends State<RecordButtonWithShadow>
      with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    late AnimationController animationController;
    late Animation<double> animation;
    //String _buttonText = 'Record'.toUpperCase();
    late bool _isRecording = false;

    @override
    void initState() {
      animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      );
      animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi).animate(animationController);
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      RecordingInfoProvider recordingInfoProvider =
          Provider.of<RecordingInfoProvider>(context);
      _isRecording = recordingInfoProvider.getRecordingStatus();
      //_isRecording = RecordingState.isRecording;

      var decorationRecording = BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.size * 0.35),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: kRecordButtonShadowColor.withOpacity(0.25),
            spreadRadius: widget.size * 0.1,
            blurRadius: widget.size * 0.2,
            offset: Offset(0, widget.size * 0.3),
          ),
        ],
      );

      var decorationNotRecording = BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: kRecordButtonShadowColor.withOpacity(0.4),
            spreadRadius: widget.size * 0.05,
            blurRadius: widget.size * 0.15,
            offset: Offset(0, widget.size * 0.09),
          ),
        ],
      );

      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          //SHADOW
          child: Container(
            decoration:
                //widget.isRecording ? decorationRecording : decorationNotRecording,
                _isRecording ? decorationRecording : decorationNotRecording,

            //BUTTON
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
              height: widget.size,
              width: widget.size,
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius:
                    //widget.isRecording
                    _isRecording
                        ? BorderRadius.circular(100)
                        : BorderRadius.circular(widget.size / 2),
                onTap: () {
                  recordingInfoProvider.toggleRecordingStatus();
                  widget.toggleRecording;
                },
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: animation,
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Transform.rotate(
                          angle: animation.value,
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      //widget.isRecording
                                      _isRecording
                                          ? BorderRadius.circular(
                                              widget.size * 0.3)
                                          : null,
                                  shape:
                                      //widget.isRecording
                                      _isRecording
                                          ? BoxShape.rectangle
                                          : BoxShape.circle,
                                  gradient: _isRecording
                                      ? LinearGradient(
                                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                          colors: [
                                            kRecordButtonColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                                            kRecordButtonColor,
                                            kRecordButtonColor,
                                            kRecordButtonColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                                          ],
                                          stops: const [
                                            0,
                                            0.3,
                                            0.7,
                                            1,
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      : RadialGradient(
                                          colors: [
                                            kRecordButtonColor,
                                            kRecordButtonColor,
                                            kRecordButtonColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                                          ],
                                          stops: const [
                                            0,
                                            0.7,
                                            1,
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:

                                        //widget.isRecording
                                        _isRecording
                                            ? BorderRadius.circular(
                                                widget.size * 0.3,
                                              )
                                            : null,
                                    shape: _isRecording
                                        ? BoxShape.rectangle
                                        : BoxShape.circle,
                                    gradient:
                                        //widget.isRecording
                                        _isRecording
                                            ? LinearGradient(
                                                colors: [
                                                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                  kRecordButtonColor
                                                      .withOpacity(0),
                                                  kRecordButtonColor
                                                      .withOpacity(0),
                                                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                ],
                                                stops: const [
                                                  0,
                                                  0.3,
                                                  0.7,
                                                  1,
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            : RadialGradient(
                                                colors: [
                                                  kRecordButtonColor,
                                                  kRecordButtonColor,
                                                  kRecordButtonColor
                                                      .withOpacity(0.2),
                                                ],
                                                stops: const [
                                                  0,
                                                  0.7,
                                                  1,
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                  ),
                                  child:
                                      //!widget.isRecording
                                      !_isRecording
                                          ? SizedBox(
                                              width: 250.0,
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: DefaultTextStyle(
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: widget.size * 0.12,
                                                    letterSpacing: 3,
                                                  ),
                                                  child: AnimatedTextKit(
                                                    animatedTexts: [
                                                      TyperAnimatedText(
                                                        'Record'.toUpperCase(),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                    totalRepeatCount: 1,
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      // startStopRecording();
                                                      // animateController();
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          : null),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

I can pass the function as a parameter but then how do I update the boolean value?!. Also, currently I am getting an error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
".

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of passing the function and boolean to the grandchild widget is correct. Regarding updating the boolean, it must be done from the parent widget.

I think I spotted a bug in your code but I am not sure since I don't have the full code, in the parent widget:

```
toggleRecording: getRecorderFn(),
```

Should be replaced with:

```
toggleRecording: getRecorderFn,
```

or

```
toggleRecording: () => getRecorderFn(),
```

The way you are sending the function is wrong since you are not sending the function but rather its return, aka when the widget is built, your code will call `getRecorderFn()` and return its result. Again I am not sure about the return value of `getRecoderFn()` this might be intentional but I don't have the rest of the code to judge.

Regarding the error, more details are required.

Comment: "It must be done from the parent widget"  - how?  How do I maintain it globally for the state of the app?

Comment: Incase you need to maintain a state for the entire app, I suggest that you use a state management approach, or you can lift the state up to a higher parent, but this is not recommended as it will cause a lot of boilerplate code and wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: I  just need a boolean to sync multiple widgets...

Comment: You can use the method that is present in the answer above

Comment: I am already using it, that doesn't help. The method does not update boolean and the state. I have updated the code.

Comment: You are still updating the static feild, do it as I shown in my example it will work. Don't do `RecordingState.isRecording = ` but rather `isRecording = `

Comment: I changed the code and I am using the static field anymore, yet somehow it doesn't work. .

Comment: Please update the code in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238302/discussion-between-who-aditya-nawandar-and-mohammad-kurjieh).

Comment: Updated the code